# Обращение к конкретной ссылке, которая соответствует конкретному span

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
<div class="booking">
    <div class="booking-date">
        <span>19 мая</span><br>
        понедельник
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">11:00</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">12:00</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">13:00</a></li>
    </ul>        
</div>

    <div class="booking">
    <div class="booking-date">
        <span>23 мая</span><br>
        понедельник
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">11:00</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">12:00</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">13:00</a></li>
    </ul>        
</div>
```

Вот есть такой кусок верстки, господа. Предположим что яваскрипту могу передать конкретное значение **span** а также конкретный текст внутри **тэга a**, то есть основные параметры известны.

Теперь вопрос: как обратиться к этому конкретному **a** соответствующему конкретному **span** значения которых заранее известны? Иначе, как обратиться к ссылке с текстом 13.00 которая соответствует **span** с текстом 23 мая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/7T42U/

Но я бы посоветовал использовать вам data-* аттрибуты и доверстать примерно так:

```
<div class="booking">
<div class="booking-date">
    <span>19 мая</span><br>
    понедельник
</div>
<ul data-date="19 мая">
    <li><a href="#">11:00</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">12:00</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">13:00</a></li>
</ul>
```

Тогда можно было бы упростить селектор - http://jsfiddle.net/7T42U/1/